# Is there a way to make the text in a blob bold? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Im currently downloading a txt file on a button click but want to make the txt file more readable. Is there a way to bold the text in a blob? Only thing I've found is related more to the markup.

a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(["this text needs to be bold"]);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please also check [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Does `window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(["<b>this text needs to be bold</b>"])); ` work?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const text = "<b>This text needs to be bold!</b> ...This text doesn't.";

const a = document.querySelector("a");
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([text], { type: "text/html" }));
```

```html
<a href="#">Click me!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

What your `Blob`'s data contains is the content of a plain text file (.txt). This file format doesn't contain any styling info, so no, it's not possible to style it anyhow, neither bold nor italic or anything, except by the use of some [Unicode hacks](https://capitalizemytitle.com/bold-text-generator/) that you should avoid because your text won't be there anymore.

So what you need is to generate the data of a file that can be styled. HTML is one such format, but most text-editors will show you the markup instead of the rendering. [RTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) is another, but you'll need a library to generate this kind of files. And there might be other formats that better suit your needs, but that's on you to decide which to use.